# How can I select all records between two dates without using date fields?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, time

I have a MySQL DB and I need to be able to store dates earlier then 1970 so I need a custom way to store dates. In my case, I need to be able to store dates up to the present and as far back as history goes. Obviously earlier events in history require less accuracy - days, months, even years become less important, as we do not have this historical information. The main query involving dates will be to select records between two given dates.

I have thought to use this format:

`Year - int(6) | Month - tinyint(2) | day - tinyint (2) | time - time | AD tinyint (1) | mya - int (11)`
But when it comes to actually using data in this format it becomes difficult. For example, if I want to get all records between two dates it would be like (pseudocode not SQL):

`get all where
year between minYear and maxYear

if year == minYear, month >= minMonth

if year == maxYear, month <= maxMonth

if month == minMonth, day >= minDay

if month == maxMonth, day <= maxDay

if day == minDay, time >= minTime

if day == maxDay, time <= maxTime`

or something, which seems like a right pain. I could store seconds before/after 0 AD, but that would take up way too much data! 2011 = 6.4 billion seconds since 0 AD. Does anybody have any ideas for this problem?

Comment: why use a 4 byte signed integer to represent month when a tinyint unsigned would be more appropriate. same goes for the day (tinyint unsigned) and year (smallint).

Comment: Thanks. I'll use that (if I use this format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need at least one date to create an interval. I use one date field for start_date and an interval which can be a number of seconds or a fixed interval like ENUM(day,month,year). This depends on the data that you are working with.

For [DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html) the supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59', but this means   that although earlier values might work, there is no guarantee. I see you can use 0001-01-01 with no problems.

**FOR BC values.**
I dont know if there is a standard but I've seen systems that state their own starting point. Lets say your data will be pre AD but not longer that 1000 BC. You can state your 0 year as -2000, you apply (year- 2000) difference for all dates and maybe even build a wrapper Date class which applies only to your project. You can assign the time as an integer an do all operations with it with no problem, especially if you dont work with days or months granularities. Current calendars are not reliable to work in the past as the accuracy of date was wrongfully calculated for centuries, and repaired by some hotfixes that can do calculations pretty difficult.

```
// lets save the 1st of January 214 BC
214-2000 = -1786
save the data as 01-01-1786
// you will probably want to save it actually as 01-01-1785 
// to compensate for the loss of the year 0
```

I would recommend you to keep the date format as it will allow you to do fast DATE operation directly in mySql.

Update for calculating the [leap years](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm) in your class:

```
if year modulo 400 is 0
   then is_leap_year
else if year modulo 100 is 0
   then not_leap_year
else if year modulo 4 is 0
   then is_leap_year
else
   not_leap_year
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I'm not storing an interval I'm just storing a date. 
But I may want to retrieve dates that _fall within_ a particular interval defined by the user. 

The starting point really doesn't matter, I'm just using AD at the moment as a convention, but there really is *no theoretical upper or lower limit* to the dates I may store. I might want to store info about the big bang :)

I assumed that there was a chance that earlier dates would work with the DATE format, but guaranteeing that it will work is important, so that's why I'm looking into a custom date format.

Comment: If there is no down limit, start from BigBang -13.7 Billion years ago.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure about where to start counting. At the moment the issue is the way I store the data. I.E. DATE format won't work with an offset of 13 Billion :)

Comment: OK, I'm going to take your advice and stick with DATE. The range for DATE is 1000-9999 so I will need to offset this.   

I will write a date class. I think offset should work like this - use 2999 as the _latest_ date possible, and therefore the new zero is -7000 BC. Any events earlier than that will use a special format which I will add support for later.   

We have now lost 0 AD so to fix that, we... do something. Okay, I don't think hours will really work BC but we probably won't need it. Have I forgotten something?

Comment: I hope not, but if so you can put an update question on SO of course.

Comment: Enjoy your points. I will post an update if I have any problems.

Comment: If you offset the date then you will have issues with leap years - 1904 was a leap year but 1204 is not. Let alone when does the gregorian calendar start

Comment: And what does 7000 in the offset map to (There is no 0 AD)

Comment: @Mark see update for leap years, Hayden will have to define that in his Date class of course.

Comment: @Elzo - but MySQL will not check the correct date and so allow 29th Feb in the wrong years e.g. 4AD

Comment: @Mark true.. and will not allow 29th of Feb in the correct years. Perhaps a solution will be to create the offset as a multiple of 4, in this case 7000 as offset is ok and keep the leap years in the position. Other solution is to put the Date in a VARCHAR and only manage the dates from the programming layer. I would prefer the first version. What do you think?

Comment: @Elzo - see my answer - use day counts

Comment: @Mark that works until January 1, 4713 BC. Algorithms for using that seem to work in beetween -4900-03-01 onward. http://www.hermetic.ch/cal_stud/jdn.htm

Comment: So how do I use your new leap year code to fix the dates?

Oh, I really have no idea now! This complicates things!

Using DATE seems to be the best way to keep the queries simple, but if leap days start dropping like flies the database will be horrendous!

Comment: @Hayden to keep leap years use an offset that is multiple of 4 and add 1 to compensate for the loss of 0 year. That's it. If is real data I guess that a daily precision will be more than enough for data going back to 10k BC. I am curious about what kind of events are you saving there...

Answer (score 2):

I would store the number of days since a given day. There are various dates that can be used as the zero day. These are generically known as Julian days see [wikipaedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day)

As you are storing dates from 0 AD the I would look at the Chronological Julian Day (CJD) so all your values are positive.

As a side effect this means that you only need to look at dealing with different calendars ( e.g. when they changed to Gregorian and when start of year changed or use Islamic calendars) when you convert to or from a date when you know more detail about the actual date,

If interested in dates don't bother with seconds as these complicate things unnecessary and also mean you have to deal with larger data (ie longer than a long) and time zomes etc ....

Comment: Yeah, seconds are fairly unimportant for this project actually, but I will definitely be storing some dates *earlier* than 0 AD. I don't _think_ I will need to convert time zones much, but this way change in the future.

Answer (score 1):

It rather depends on what kind of queries you want to run.

You could store the dates as strings YYYYMMDDHHMMSS which will sort chronologically and allow you to find dates in a range. See also ISO 8601 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: but it will having problem for negative value (before AD), where greater hour is lesser in negative value

Comment: Oh, that is true. But then again, when we start to get as far back as dates before 0 AD, hours and minutes become much less important. We probably neither know nor care what time something happened back then.